# Why does MySQL sort correctly but SQLite doesn't when field is marked with quotation marks?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

In the following SQL statement, SQLite sorts correctly but MySQL does not:

[image]

However, if I don't include the quotation marks around the field names, it works correctly:

[image]

**Can anyone explain the behavior that MySQL but not SQLite would not sort correctly if a field is defined with quotation marks?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"TotalOrders"` (with double quotes) is a constant string - ordering by it doesn't do anything ... in essence you get the unsorted sequence of rows, which might seem to be correctly sorted.

You want

```
ORDER BY `TotalOrders`
```

with backticks. which is the column identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eugen's answer:

It might be worth noting that this behaviour depends on the configuration of MySQL.

The described behaviour only shows if MySQL is left in the default - non standard compliant configuration.

If it's configured to run in "ANSI mode" the double quotes are not used for string literals but for identifiers (as nearly all other DBMS).

Another solution to the problem would have been to make MySQL comply with the SQL standard by changing the SQL_MODE to "ANSI".

Then standard compliant single quotes are used for literals and the double quotes are used for identifiers.